# Update text JS function working in everything except Edge

Tags: javascript

I haven't found the right answer in any similar questions, so I hope someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a simple script that updates some text based on a range slider selection. I have noticed this works in everything except Edge, and having little experience with Javascript I'm wondering how to fix it.

The HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1" id="pick_fruit" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">

<p id="fruit_value">Pick a fruit</p>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateTextInput() {
        var fruit_range = Number(document.getElementById("pick_fruit").value);
        var fruit_value = "";

            if ( 
                fruit_range === 1 ) { 
                fruit_value = "Apples";
            }
            else if ( 
                fruit_range === 2 ) {
                fruit_value = "Oranges";
            }
            else if ( 
                fruit_range === 3 ) {
                fruit_value = "Pears";
            }

        document.getElementById('fruit_value').innerHTML = fruit_value;

    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `oninput` event to trigger the function. An object that maps ints to strings cleans up the conditional a little...

```js
const fruitMap = { 1:'Apples', 2:'Oranges', 3:'Pears' }

function updateTextInput() {
  const v = +document.getElementById("pick_fruit").value
  document.getElementById('fruit_value').innerHTML = fruitMap[v];

}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1" id="pick_fruit" 
oninput="updateTextInput()">

<p id="fruit_value">Pick a fruit</p>
```

Comment: This works. Great solution. Thanks for the quick reply, and for even improving my code!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add

`var fruit_range = Number(document.getElementById("pick_fruit").value);`

because you are already getting value from the your `function (updateTextInput())`, you need to provide an argument inside the function to get the `onchange` value. I tried to simplify the code you can test it.

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1" id="pick_fruit" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value)">
  <p id="fruit_value">Pick a fruit</p>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var fruit_value = "";
  function updateTextInput(value) {
            if (value == 1 ) { 
                this.fruit_value = "Apples";
            }
            else if (value == 2 ) {
                this.fruit_value = "Oranges";
            }
            else if (value == 3 ) {
                this.fruit_value = "Pears";
            }
         
         document.getElementById('fruit_value').innerHTML = fruit_value;
     }
 </script>
</html>
```

***Update***

Also you need to change the conditions from "===" to "==" or change the min & max to number type, as in input tag the values are in string and "===" checks both and its type but as in condition you were comparing string type to number type it will always give a empty string .